# can I use limit and count together in influxdb query

Tags: go, influxdb

I'm getting error while using limit and count together in influxdb.

```
let data = `from(bucket:"test") `;
data += '|> range(start: 0)';
    data += '|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "test")';
    data += '|>group()';
    data += '|>sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: true)';
    data= '|> limit(n:10)';
```

up to this, I will get o/p. However, when I try to include count too, the results will be wrong.

Comment: Are you expecting the count return 10, instead of the number of holistic list of the results? I think count and limit functions are incompatibility in semantics.

Comment: if there is some error, please update you're question and mention it.